# What term has replaced the term “microcomputing” from 1986?

Tags: word-usage

[image]

Why has the term "microcomputing" been used less and less since 1986-87 ([ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=microcomputing&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=))?

What term has replaced the term "microcomputing" since 1986?

Comment: Why do you assume it has been *replaced*? When technology goes out of use, it quite typically takes its name down with it.

Comment: The term "personal computer" replaced micro-computing..

Answer (score 3):

In the early days of computers, computers were huge machines that filled gymnasium-sized rooms. Over time, they got smaller until a market segment of computers that could sit on a desk appeared. Those computers were called microcomputers.

Eventually, all computers were miniaturized to the same scale; "mainframe" computers were just slightly bigger, more expensive micros. There was no longer a need to distinguish between microcomputers and any other kind of computer so [the micro- prefix disappeared](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=microcomputing,microcomputer&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=).

As for what "replaced" it, the various other computer terms have replaced it. Microcomputing is just computing with a computer.

Comment: A desk-top sized *micro-computer* was no longer so *micro* when an iphone sized smart phone now has more computing power.

Comment: There also used to be a class of "minicomputers" between mainframe and micro.

Comment: @bib an iphone has more computing power than any "microcomputer" ever did, but my desktop computer is still way faster than any iphone.